# Deploy dacpac through VSTS only if it's been modified since last deploy

Tags: build, azure-devops

In the deploy dacpac step in VSTS, you can set the database to only run based on custom conditions. The conditions examples are based on VSTS build information, and I can't find any documentation on using conditions from a connected Azure subscription or dacpac metadata. In the [conditional page](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/process/conditions#version), they have a version variable which seems like it might be useful, but I can't find other information about it.

Basically, when the dacpac step is triggered, I want to check metadata against existing data, conditionally run the build step, and update metadata. Is this possible through a VSTS build step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can add an user defined variable (such as the variable `result` with default value `0`) in the VSTS build definition. And with the value `1` to run the dacpac step, with value `0` to skip the step.

Detail steps as below:

- Add a **PowerShell task** with two operations before the dacpac step:

  1. Check if there has new changes for the existing data.

     If the metadata only stored in Azure, you can refer [this way](https://ppolyzos.com/2016/02/09/connecting-powershell-to-your-azure-subscription/) to connect with Azure in powershell. If the metadata also stored in the repository (such as a git repo) you build with, you can also check the update in the repository.
  2. Set the `result` variable value based on if there the metadata is updated or not.

     If the data is updated, then change the `result` variable with value `1`:

     ```
     Write-Host ("##vso[task.setvariable variable=result]1")
     ```

     Else, do not change the value (keep the value with `0`)

  Since the data are managed in git VCS, you can check if the data is update or not in git repo. If the data is changed, then change the variable `result` as `1`. detail powershell script as below:

  ```
  $files=$(git diff HEAD HEAD~1 --name-only)
  echo "changed files as below: $files"
  if ($files -contains 'filename')
    Write-Host ("##vso[task.setvariable variable=result]1")
  ```
- Set **conditions** for the dacpac step:

  In the task, select **Custom conditions** for Run this task. If you want to run this task when succeeding and the variable `result` variable is `1`, you can the express:

  ```
  and(succeeded(), eq(variables['result'], '1'))
  ```

Now if the `result` with the value `0`, the dacpac step will be skipped, is the `result` with value `1`, the dacpack will be executed.

Comment: What's a good way to check for new changes? I was thinking I could store a hash of the most recent dacpac deploy for each database in a storage table and compare that to a hash of the current database, then update it, but if VSTS or Azure has some sort of built in version control that would be better

Comment: Does the data also managed in source control (git or TFVC)? If the data managed in VCS, there does has easier way. Else you can use the way as you mentioned.

Comment: The data is managed in git, and the infra is built through VSTS

Comment: I added the powershell script by checking update in git repo. You can have a try.

Comment: The powershell code you gave compares the values between the current and last commit. What I want to compare is which commit was used for the current VSTS build and the most recent VSTS build

Comment: Are there build variables available for the last build?

Comment: What do you mean last build? For the changed value only works for the following tasks after the task that you change the value.